# Postgres not using index for start with query

Tags: postgresql

I have a `usernames` table with a `username` string field, I have a "start with" query and trying both pattern and regex matching

```
SELECT username FROM usernames WHERE username LIKE 'foo%';
```

```
SELECT username FROM usernames WHERE username ~ '^foo';
```

I have a `b-tree` index on the `username` field and `SET ENABLE_SEQSCAN =false;` , When I `EXPLAIN` the abovementioned queries, the query planner uses `SEQ_SCAN (Seq Scan)`

I am using PostgreSQL 13.4 , tried `VACUUM (VERBOSE, ANALYZE) usernames` and `REINDEX TABLE usernames` too

What's wrong here?

Comment: Please show the index definition and your locale.  My guess is that your locale is not `c` and the index was not defined with text_pattern_ops: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-opclass.html

Comment: `LC_COLLATE` and `LC_CTYPE` both are `fa_IR`

Comment: @Jeremy Thanks a lot, you are right, `text_pattern_ops` solved the problem :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best index for the `LIKE` query would be

```
CREATE INDEX ON usernames (username text_pattern_ops);
```

For the regular expression match, you would need a trigram index, but it is easier to use the `LIKE` version instead.

Comment: As I have already a `b-tree` index on `username` field and my query is start with query, the `b-tee` index is appropriate and I don't want to add overload to database for a redundant index

Comment: Drop the other index. The index I suggest works just as well for equality searches. Only to support inequality conditions (`<`, `<=`, `>` and `>=`) or `ORDER BY` you need a normal B-tree index.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally by default once the B-tree index has been created it should be using the Index Scan, the only condition otherwise is-

**using the LIKE keyword followed by a wildcard and then a string ('%nik') cannot use an index defined on the column but if it is vice versa then the index is used ('Slo%')**

Try **passing hints to the Query plan builder**, also is Index_scan enabled?

```
/*+IndexScan(username)*/ select username from usernames where username like 'foo%'
```

Comment: I asked that my query is START WITH, not END WITH

Comment: `SHOW enable_indexscan` is `on`

Comment: AFAIK there is no index hint in PostgreSQL ,how to hint?

Comment: refer this [link](https://pghintplan.osdn.jp/pg_hint_plan.html)

Comment: That's an extension, there's no reason to believe the op has it installed.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of 'where' condition given in the statement (username LIKE 'foo%'). Here You are trying to fetch all rows which meet this pattern. Therefore
it required to check all rows which is started with character "foo" and ignore the index.

Comment: According to documentation The optimizer can also use a B-tree index for queries involving the pattern matching operators LIKE and ~ if the pattern is a constant and is anchored to the beginning of the string — for example, col LIKE 'foo%' or col ~ '^foo', but not col LIKE '%bar'.

Comment: What percentage of rows return by these queries?

Comment: A few, less than 1%

Comment: Consider that I am using `SET ENABLE_SEQSCAN =false;`